# System Clipboard Vim within TMUX within SSH session

Tags: vim, ssh, tmux

I have vim open inside tmux inside an ssh session. How can I make vim use my laptop's system clipboard as the default copy paste? The default `set clipboard=unamed` isn't working. Both systems are Ubuntu in case that matters.

Comment: [This answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/326871/using-clipboard-through-ssh-in-vim) or [this blog post](https://defuse.ca/blog/clipboard-over-ssh-with-vim.html) talk about doing this over SSH, but tmux may throw an extra monkeywrench into things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do two things.

1. On your remote system, install a clipboard-aware Vim (and the X dependencies needed for clipboard support):

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
   ```
2. On your local system, start your ssh session with X11 forwarding enabled:

   ```
   $ ssh -X user@hostname
   ```

   See `$ man ssh` for the security implications of X11 forwarding.

Comment: Would I have to use gvim in that case or would I still be able to use vim in terminal with X11 forwarding support?

Comment: No, you don't need to *use* GVim. On Debian derivatives, `gvim` and `vim` are actually links to the same binary called with different arguments. The whole point of installing the `vim-gtk` package is to get a binary that is built against X11, with the "clipboard" feature enabled. Calling it as `vim` or as `gvim` therefore doesn't matter: you still get clipboard support.

Answer (score 6):

Clipboard integration feature (PASTE64/OSC52) is helpful if your terminal emulator supports it. For example, iTerm2 supports it (I am not sure about Ubuntu).

Add this function to your "remote" `.vimrc`. 
yank something and run `:OscCopy`. It works even it is inside tmux session.

```
function! OscCopy()
  let encodedText=@"
  let encodedText=substitute(encodedText, '\', '\\\\', "g")
  let encodedText=substitute(encodedText, "'", "'\\\\''", "g")
  let executeCmd="echo -n '".encodedText."' | base64 | tr -d '\\n'"
  let encodedText=system(executeCmd)
  if $TMUX != ""
    "tmux
    let executeCmd='echo -en "\x1bPtmux;\x1b\x1b]52;;'.encodedText.'\x1b\x1b\\\\\x1b\\" > /dev/tty'
  else
    let executeCmd='echo -en "\x1b]52;;'.encodedText.'\x1b\\" > /dev/tty'
  endif
  call system(executeCmd)
  redraw!
endfunction
command! OscCopy :call OscCopy()
```

[gist](https://gist.github.com/greymd/66affaf1b659add82d120cffb03c2b35)

Comment: Note that some terminals (i.e. kitty) need a clipboard to be explicitly set. So in the above, `52;;` should be `52;p;` for those terminals. (As of kitty 0.13.3, `p` works while `c` doesn't. YMMV)

Comment: Hmm. Just discovered that this method fails when I select more than ~10 lines. Anyone else experience this (an error flashes briefly)?

Answer (score 0):

For the osc52 copy, there's plugin available:

[Plugin for osc52](https://github.com/fcpg/vim-osc52)

it should solve the issue